# What is a "FPE_FLTSUB: subscript out of range" signal?

Tags: c, signals, sigfpe

In `sys/signal.h`, one of the possible codes for a `SIGFPE` is a `FPE_FLTSUB` for which the comment just says "subscript out of range -NOTIMP". I'm on OS X 10.9, but it appears to be in [glibc as well](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=bits/siginfo.h;h=db268d53b1c6ca77c5c589b44c38152836e5ee74;hb=HEAD#l112).

It isn't one of the standard IEEE exceptions, so what is it, and when is it raised?

Comment: It's for accessing outside the bounds of an array.

Comment: @Barmar Do you  have any more info or links? I thought C arrays weren't bounds checked: is it guaranteed to always signal on out of bounds access?

Comment: They aren't required to be bounds-checked. But that doesn't mean they couldn't be. If an implementation checks bounds, they could use this signal to report it. Also, C isn't the only language in the world, other languages do bounds checking.

Comment: Note also that it says "Not implemented". It's just a placeholder for a signal to be used if such a thing is ever implemented.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't get the acronym. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD generates this code with `SIGFPE` when the x86 `BOUND` instruction detects an array index out of bounds. It looks like Linux generates `SIGSEGV` instead.

This is not particularly important, since the `BOUND` instruction is best avoided. It is not available in 64-bit mode and on most modern processors it is very slow even if the index is within bounds.